# I am using youtubeplayerview library of pierfrancescosoffritti youtubeplayerview and i got error while uploading on playstore for android tv

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRbjZ.png)
ndroid tv is rejected because of this media playback and dpad control issues so how to resolve it please give me solution i am stuck..

i tried setonkeylistener of youtubeplayerview but not worked,

i am using pierfrancescosoffritti youtube playerview but i cannot figure it out how to resolve this issues for android tv app playstore. please give detailed solution of it Thanks..

Comment: https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player/issues/888

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.